# Google Fit API Sign in works only on one device

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

After getting the Google Fit API to authenticate user and read data on the phone I use for debugging, I sent the debug.apk to my friend's phone to test it. I checked the Cloud Platform console, the API dashboard shows the requests.
However, it is not working on any device except mine. I tried with testing mode on google cloud(all the emails were added as testers), it did not worked. When I publish the app on google cloud, nothing changes, same problem again, getting result code 0.
I would like to know if problem is with google cloud platform or I should wait some time...

Comment: Please provide more information about the issue. Did you correctly configure the app to authorize the requests using OAuth 2.0? Did you check that you have the correct permission to provide access to other users to your app?

Comment: Just edited the post. Everything is working perfectly on my device. On Cloud Console, API is published, it says every user will be able to use the API.

Comment: When publishing your app in Cloud APIs, you still need to configure the way the App will authenticate the users to obtain information from/to it. Please review this article about Authorizing requests for Google Fit.https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization

Comment: Also could you please provide more information about code 0? You're able to install the app on another phone and won’t connect or you can’t even install?

Comment: I can install the app on the other phone. It works perfectly, but google fit is not authenticating the user. When the popup with accounts shows and you select the account, it just disappears and nothing happens.

Comment: About publishing my app in Cloud APIs... I did that just in case there is a problem with "Testing" phase. However, I'd like to revert it back to "Testing" status since all of the emails that are testing the app are added as a testers, and, at the end, app is in development process, so it should be marked as "Testing".